# Is is possible to make a cross-database foreign key?

Tags: laravel, database-migration, cross-database

I made migration with  foreign key 'user_id' to a table 'users' that is in another database: 
This generates an error when i type (php artisan migrate).

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
 : alter table `safetyreports` add constraint safetyreports_user_id_foreign
 foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Now laravel made the table except the 'user_id' column.  How can i accomplish this?

This is my migration code:

```
Schema::create('safetyreports', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('afdeling');
            $table->string('contractor');
            $table->string('directe chef');
            $table->string('ploeg');
            $table->string('team');
            $table->string('plant_afd');
            $table->string('datum');
            $table->string('plaats');
            $table->string('tijd');
            $table->string('omschrijving');
                        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is my User model code:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
protected $table = 'users';
```

I have tested my Users model. It works. I tested it with User:all() and then displaying all the users on my sreen.

Is this making a foreign key cross database tables possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible full stop. I don't think it's a Laravel issue (okay Laravel is mistakenly allowing you to try), but more that you're trying to do the impossible. You could, of course try to get away without having the FK constraint, but then I think Laravel *will* be your problem, in that it'll try to JOIN the tables. This is possible in MySQL, but only if you use `database`.`table` nomenclature, and I don't think Laravel does that as it assumes you're sticking to one database per query. That said, I'm not 100% on that, this is just my gut feeling.